# If $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \cdot \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is 0 at integer values, does it mean that all $a_k = 0$?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

For a sequence of real numbers $\left(a_k\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, does the fact that

$$
g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \cdot \frac{x^k}{k!} = 0,  \forall x \in \{1, 2, 3, ... \}
$$

imply that $a_k = 0, \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, ... \}$?

In the case where the property is true $\forall x \in \left(0, \infty \right)$, one can use differentiation and Taylor expansion ([as was done in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96321/complete-statistic-poisson-distribution)) to conclude that $a_k = 0, \forall k = \{0, 1, 2, ... \}$.

I don't think the same approach works in the case where the values taken by $x$ are discrete.

I think it's enough to show that the infinite matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
1^0 & 1^1 & 1^2 & ... \\
2^0 & 2^1 & 2^2 & ... \\
3^0 & 3^1 & 3^2 & ... \\
. & . & . \\
. & . & . \\
. & . & . \\
\end{pmatrix}

has a determinant of $0$, but I'm not sure where to start. I don't think an approach related to generating functions will work either, since only the values at positive integer $x$ are known.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed with this?

Comment: No, consider $
\sin (\pi x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{k - 1} \pi ^{2k - 1} \frac{{x^{2k - 1} }}{{(2k - 1)!}}} 
$. The odd index $a_k$'s are non-zero.

Comment: @Gary You could consider posting that as an answer as well. Your call, of course. Not easy to phrase it as "a hint" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider
$$
\sin (\pi x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{k - 1} \pi ^{2k - 1} \frac{{x^{2k - 1} }}{{(2k - 1)!}}} .
$$
In this example, with your notation,
$$
a_{2k - 1}  = ( - 1)^{k - 1} \pi ^{2k - 1} \neq 0,\quad a_{2k}  = 0,
$$
yet the power series vanishes at integer values of $x$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had a hunch that circular functions might work, but I couldn't arrive at anything concrete. Thank you for the answer!